# django picture is set to one large size

Tags: python, html, django

I am very new to **django**, so i prefer getting a simple answer.I got this slideshow from a website,it is displaying the all images in **one** size ,this is my code .

```
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="200">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{%static 'images/2.jpg' %}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{%static 'images/3.jpg' %}" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="{%static 'images/4.jpg' %}" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

My problem is that images are displayed in one(large) size,i want to display the images in their original size,this slideshow makes them all one large size.
 *any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted changes the size of the pictures. Presumably you have some CSS classes - perhaps `w-100` - that does this. If so, why not try removing it?

Comment: Please share the CSS code for `w-100`. I hope the size is defined there.

Comment: @DKAnsh i am not sure  what  you mean

Comment: @timmy, Where is the CSS code for class `w-100`. You have used `w-100` class for  `<img>` tag. Please post the CSS code for `w-100` than only we will be able to help you.